# pyobjc application load-time improvement

Tags: python, cocoa, py2app, pyobjc

I have built a pyobjc app and found that it seems to take a long time to load.

I've added logging to measure the time it takes to load each step. Before getting to AppHelper.runEventLoop() the app took up to 10 seconds, sometime 20 seconds to load.

The strip-down code looks like this:

```
import objc
objc.setVerbose(DEBUG) # debug flag True/False
from ApplicationView import ApplicationView
from ApplicationDelegate import ApplicationDelegate
....
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
AppHelper.runEventLoop()
```

The **ApplicationView** and **ApplicationDelegate** are custom modules that implement the Cocoa application user interface and have many imports. I think this is where it takes a long time.

My questions are:

1. If the imports in the imported modules affect the load time, can I add code there to check if that particular import is necessarily yet or not, and would this help with the load time?
2. If I want to add a splash screen, how can I do it if worst case I cannot make any changes to the ApplicationView and ApplicationDelegate modules, and need to wait for them to load.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all imports in the custom modules seem to help as they are only used when that particular window (NSWindowController) is loaded. This is because I structure the application by NSWindowController, so I only load the main one in the applicationDidLoad in the ApplicationDelegate class that subclass NSObject.